# calculate the maximum number of linearly independent subsets

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure if this question has been asked before, apologies if I am repeating this question again.

My question is as follows:

given a set i know how to find all the subsets of the set.

But what I would really like to know is how do i find all linearly independent subsets that can be obtained from this super set.

Thanks,
Bhavya

Comment: What do you mean by linear independence? A set in itself has no linear structure, and the phrase "linear independence" is meaningless.

Comment: @bhavya: If your set $S$ is a finite subset of a say $3$-dimensional vector space, then you need only worry about subsets of $s$ that have $3$ or fewer elements, for the other subsets are not linearly independent. Then you can test all such "small" subsets of $S$ for linear independence. Testing a single subset of $S$, say with $3$ elements, is easy, you probably have had to do it. I do not know any efficient way of testing a large number of subsets of $S$, except for the tedious process of testing one subset, then another, and so on.

Comment: @bhavya: As for calculating the maximum, it could easily be that all the subsets of $S$ with $3$ or fewer elements are linearly independent. So if $S$ has $n$ elements drawn from a $3$-dimensional vector space, the number of linearly independent subsets of $S$ could be as large as $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}$.

Comment: @Andre thank you for the explanation it makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method (not efficient necessarily). If the subset is finite (or has a finite generator), let call it $S=\lbrace a_i\rbrace_{i=1}^n$, on a v.e. $E$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}$, try to solve the equation $$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ia_i=0$$ where $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{K}$. Then if exist $\lambda_i\neq0$, eliminate $a_i$ from $S$. Repeat until the solution is $\lambda_i=0, \forall i$. Then, all the subsets of  $S$ (actualized) will be l.i. After try to interchange elements from $S$ with the eliminated preserving the linear independence.